# How to redirect from spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a `MainRedirectController` and all requests and responses will redirect from this controller. How can I send request parameter from `mainRedirect` method to `page1` method and send response parameter from `page1` method to `mainRedirect` method?

```
public class MainRedirectController{

  public ModelAndView mainRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String page = ServletRequestUtils.getStringParameter(request, "page", null);
    if(page.equals("page1")){
       //redirect request to page1 controller and 
       //return reponse coming from page1 controller
    }else if(....){
       ...
    }

  }
}


public class Page1Controller{

  public ModelAndView page1(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     response.getOutputStream().print("{\"completed\": \"1\"}");
     response.getOutputStream().flush();
     return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I wonder why you want to pass through single controller? Is that any specific reason?

Comment: That won't work you either need a proxy or provide better mapping in the controllers. You do't need such a large controller for the processing (that is the whole point of the `DispatcherServlet =` and the `@RequestMapping` annotations.

Comment: @ShaikElias I have a client application and with this application users can do some operations. Problem is this client application has no authentication info. So I created a page with anonymous access(MainRedirectController). With this controller I need to redirect user  requests to some specific controllers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return "redirect:" view to that page. 
Just use it as constructor parameter:

```
if(page.equals("page1")){
   return new ModelAndView("redirect:/page1MappingValue")
}
```

page1MappingValue here is the address to your page1 depending on the mapping.

You can read more about redirects here:

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward

Also if you need to get a response just inside the method and you don't need return it directly, you can use RestTemplate-s:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

It will allow you to get a response and use it on the back-end inside your logic.